# how to make custom nested layout in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, layout-manager

[image]

im trying to do this form in java
and im getting this results [image]

how do i place b6 on the top center
and b4 on the bottom center
and how can i change split panel location

Comment: Looks like you are using a FlowLayout. Start by reading the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and then determine which layout manager of combination of layout manager you can use. Maybe use a vertical BoxLayout for the label, split panel and panel containing the buttons. We can't give you the exact layout managers to use because a picture is not a requirement. What happens when the frame is resized? Do the components resize? Should the components be centered horizontally or vertically etc.

Comment: when the frame is resized nothing change , they stay in the same position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

You need to break down your needs and focus on which layouts are going to give you what you want.

I'd start with a `BorderLayout` as it gives you the ability to have two components at the top and bottom, which honour the preferred sizes of those components and the centre component can be allowed to resize based on the available space of the window.

The title is simple, as it's just a `JLabel`.  For the buttons, I've used a `JPanel` using a `GridBagLayout`, as it will centre the components by default, BUT it won't fill them components evenly, so beware of that.

Both the leading and trailing components of the `JSplitPane` I used a `GridBagLayout` as it allows the child components to be laid out in the centre of the container and allows a large amount of flexibility in terms of how the components are managed.

I've used a `EmptyBorder` to add some padding around some parts of the components.  There are several ways to achieve this, but this is just one way.

Beware, `GridBagLayout` is very flexible, but it's a complex layout manager.

[image: Simple Example]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Traducteur");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

            add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            JPanel actions = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            actions.add(new JButton("Help"));
            actions.add(new JButton("Exit"));
            actions.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

            add(actions, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();

            JPanel leadingPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            leadingPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(40, 20, 40, 20));
            JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
            DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
            model.addElement("In English");
            comboBox.setModel(model);
            leadingPane.add(comboBox);

            splitPane.setLeftComponent(leadingPane);

            JPanel trailingPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            trailingPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(40, 20, 40, 20));
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;

            trailingPane.add(new JTextField("Some text"), gbc);
            trailingPane.add(new JTextField("Some more text"), gbc);

            splitPane.setRightComponent(trailingPane);

            add(splitPane);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Left of split pane, put the combo box in a `GridBagLayout` (with no constraints) to center it it horizontally and vertically.
- Right of split pane. `GridLayout` with vertical padding. Add an `EmptyBorder` to get the padding around the components.
- Put the split pane in the `CENTER` of a `BorderLayout`
- The `Traducteur` label goes in the `PAGE_START` of the border layout.
- The `Help` / `Exit` buttons in a panel with `FlowLayout`. Put that panel in the `PAGE_END` of the border layout.

/fin

Here is how that might look:

[image]